# Does Jersey expose a way to manually bind dependencies to an instance?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jax-rs

Jersey (and JAX-RS in general) allows simple dependency injection as follows:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource {
    @Context private Application application;
    ...
    }
```

Jersey first creates the class, then it binds dependencies to it. Is this a mechanism I can re-use for instances whose lifecycle I control entirely?

For example, consider an interface with some unknown implementations.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public boolean isHappy();
}
```

Suppose I have a list of these in one of my provider singletons, for example, an ExceptionMapper. It would be initialized in some subclass of Application.

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    private List<MyInterface> list;
    public ExceptionMapper(List<MyInterface> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
        for (MyInterface item : list) {
            // Manually bind dependencies here?
            if (item.isHappy()) {
                return Response.ok("Nope, no errors here. Promise.").build();
            }
        }
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

And finally, suppose there's a specific implementation of this interface that needs access to the Application:

```
public class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
    @Context private Application application; // Can't do this
    @Override
    public boolean isHappy() {
        MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) application;
        return myApp.shouldIgnoreExceptions(); // NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Is there a way to bind contexts for all of the implementations of my interface? Or do I need to find a way to get Jersey to manage all implementations (by making them providers)? Or must I resort to CDI to perform dependency injection?

Note that I'm using Jersey 1.17.1, and I'd like to avoid defining any particular dependency as being part of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The JAX-RS way is to implement your own `ContextResolver` for `MyInterface`. Then you can manage the implementation of the contexts inside the context resolved. Context resolver is provider and is managed by Jersey, but not the MyInterface implementations.